# C++ is possible to make only one method templated?

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, c++03

I have a class and I need only one template method, like this:

```
/* A.h */

class A {
public: 
  void foo() const; 
private:
  template <class T> 
  void foo2(const T& t, const std::string& s) {
     /* */
  }
}
```

This compiles fine, but if in the `foo` specialization I try to call `foo2` I get errors:

```
/* A.cpp */

void A::foo() {
   this->foo2(1, "test");
}
```

The error is:

```
passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void A::foo2(const T&, const
string&) [with T = int, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’
discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: And the errors are...?

Comment: @SteveTownsend "what T to infer from the literal 1" - well, it could infer `int` without problems, since the literal `1` is of type `int`...

Comment: There is no `foo` specialization as it is not a template. And you should tell us what the error is, we usually do not practice telepathy here

Comment: @SteveTownsend don't works..

Comment: You've got problems with const-correctness and a part of the error message is missing. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), please.

Comment: OK, that's why I added it as a comment

Comment: Go to ideone.  Create a minimal example of the code that generates your compile error there.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are showing the `foo` you are using? Looks like `foo` is `const`.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka you're right, I bad copied in post! ):

Comment: Now take another look at your post and see how nonsensical the title is.

Comment: come on, it could be usefull anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I think you missed const modifier for void foo() in your example, didn't you?

If my assumption is correct, put a const modifier for foo2 too.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling on the same object a non-const function `foo2` from const function `foo`. Hence the error. BTW `this` in the call is not necessary:

```
this->foo2(1, "test");
```

the following will do too:

```
foo2(1, "test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `;` at the end of your class declaration and your const correctness seems to be inconsistent. This compiles for me in vc12:

```
/* A.h */

class A {
public:
    void foo() const;
private:
    template <class T>
    void foo2(const T& t, const std::string& s) const {
        /* */
    }
};
void A::foo() const {
    this->foo2(1, "test");
}
```